# jQuery detect if .find(' ').text() is defined or not

Tags: jquery, string, object, undefined, typeof

I have such a code

```
if ($('#bar #username').text()!=$('.widget-' + widget.id).find('.user').text())
{
//do something
}
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't go through if `$('.widget-' + widget.id).find('.user').text()` does not exist/ underfined.

How to check if it is defined?

I've tried `if (typeof $('.widget-' + widget.id).find('.user') === "undefined")` to check whether it is defined or not, but it doesn't help because

`alert (typeof $('.widget-' + widget.id).find('.user'))` shows `Object`,

`alert (typeof $('.widget-' + widget.id).find('.user').text())` shows `String`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As per [the jQuery FAQ](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/faq/how-do-i-test-whether-an-element-exists/), check the `length` property:

```
if ($('.widget-' + widget.id).find('.user').length) {
    // it exists
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to see whether a jQuery object matched any DOM elements, use `$("whatever").length` -- it will be nonzero.